# Z score table question

Tags: probability

I have a kind off rookie question for you that i've tried to figure out for the past 1.5 hours.

> Find the critical value that corresponds to a 90% confidence level.

I know that the answer is 1.645. But i tried to look it up on the Z score table, but i couldn't figure out how to read it. I did the following: 0.9+1 = 1.90.

I then look at the left side for 1.9 and on the top i search for 0.0, the number that is stated there is 0.9713. Which isnt true.

Can someone explain me please how to use the Z-table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Z-score tables show cumulative probability up to the given value of the statistic Z.  I.e., they drop the right tail but not the left tail.  If you want to have 90% in your retained range and drop *both* tails (which you do), you need to figure out how much you're dropping from each tail.

Since in total you're dropping 10% and the distribution is left-right symmetric, you want to drop 5% from each tail.  To find where the right limit is, find 0.95 in the table and read out the matching Z-score from the column and row.  This is the right end-point (cutting off a 5% tail to the right).  By symmetry, minus that is the left end-point (cutting off a 5% tail to the left).  What does that leave?  90% in the middle.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I understand a bit better how the table works. But when I look for the number 0.95 on the right-side I come under the number 0.8289. On the left side it is 0.1711. I still cant figure out how I can come on the answer 1.645

Comment: You are reading the table wrong. You are looking to find the standard deviation when the cumulative probability is .95 , but what you did was look up the cumulative probabilities at .95 and -.95 standard deviations. Do you know what the values in a z score table represent?

Comment: @user3055277:  As described in the answer, find "0.95" in the sea of numbers, then find the row and column header for that entry and assemble the Z-score from those two headers.  You should be using the table "backwards" from the way you seem to be epecting (i.e. from the body numbers to the headers instead of from headers to the body numbers).

Answer (score 0):

If you want a 90% confidence interval, you probably want it to be symmetric, and so you will want 5% at each of the tails. Depending on if you are looking at a negative or positive z-score table, you should look for an entry that reads 0.05 or 0.95=1-0.05=(1+0.90)/2.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I understand  a bit better how the table works. But when I look for the number 0.95 on the right-side I come under the number 0.8289. On the left side it is 0.1711.

I still cant figure out how I can come on the answer 1.645